# Cannot connect to RabbitMQ over the LAN

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I have a running RabbitMQ cluster on 2 machines, let's call them rmq1 and rmq2.

I am using a PHP driver to connect to the nodes. When i run the code from rmq1 or 2 and my host is `localhost`, the connection works. But when i try to connect from another node from across the network, the connection fails with the error below

```
[PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException]                 
  Error reading data. Received 0 instead of expected 7 bytes
```

I have verified my RabbitMQ is listening on all interfaces, like so :

```
 sudo netstat -plunt | grep 5672
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2749/beam.smp   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2749/beam.smp   
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      2749/beam.smp
```

And i tried telnetting from the lan machine to host

```
telnet 192.168.0.40 5672
Trying 192.168.0.40...
Connected to 192.168.0.40.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

That works too. So what gives?

Comment: Do you have firewall on these servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you are using guest login to connect to RabbitMQ server. Guest login can only works through localhost, you have to add another user with enough rights to access RabbitMQ other than localhost.

Refer: [RabbitMQ Access Control](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html)

Comment: Thanks Shubham. I switched to another user and it worked